# After delete a image file programmatically in java, ImageIcon is showing the deleted file from the path

Tags: java, imageicon

My project is loading an ImageIcon which is deleted image from the path.

Initially, I have loaded a image from a file path to an ImageIcon, after that I deleted the image file from the path. the again, I tried to load the image from the deleted path to Same ImageIcon object, it is showing the deleted image.

```
    File file = new File(Utility.generate_file_path("Ec_resized_image\\ansi.png"));
    System.out.println(Utility.generate_file_path("Ec_resized_image\\ansi.png")
        + " : " + file.exists());

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Utility.generate_file_path("Ec_resized_image\\ansi.png"));           
    System.out.println("Width: " + icon.getIconWidth());//Here it the image width is showing 1920 
    file.delete();       //here I am deleting the file 

    System.out.println(Utility.generate_file_path("Ec_resized_image\\ansi.png") + " : " + file.exists()); // here file.exists() says false. 

    icon = new ImageIcon(Utility.generate_file_path("Ec_resized_image\\ansi.png")); // Again loading the deleted path
    System.out.println("Width: " + icon.getIconWidth());////Here it the image width is showing again 1920
```

Comment: Not sure about the internals, but have you tried invoking `icon.getimage().flush()`? From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#flush()), this might release cached resources.

Answer (score 2):

`ImageIcon(filename)` delegates the actual loading of the image to `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename)` (maybe not defined as such by the API, but I see this in the source.)

From the Javadoc of `Toolkit.getImage()`:

> The underlying toolkit attempts to resolve multiple requests with the same filename to the same returned Image.
>   ...
>   If the image data contained in the specified file changes, **the `Image` object returned from this method may still contain stale information** which was loaded **from the file after a prior call**.

This javadoc then continues:

> Previously loaded image data can be manually discarded by calling the `flush()` method on the returned `Image`.

So, as Mena suggested, `icon.getImage().flush()` should do the trick.